# How to get only the object file without main function by ghc?

Tags: haskell, ghc

**[Source Code]**

> data FooBar = Foo | Bar

**[Command]**

> $ ghc -c foo_bar.hs
>   foo_bar.hs:1:0: The function 'main' is not defined in module 'Main'

**[Configuration]**

> Glasgow Haskell Compiler, Version 6.12.3, for Haskell 98, stage 2 booted by GHC
>   version 6.10.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should define your type in a module, and then compile it:

```
module Test where
data FooBar = Foo | Bar
```

By invoking `ghc -c foo_bar.hs`, the object file `foo_bar.o` will be generated without having to define `main`.

Comment: $ ghc -c -no-hs-main foo_bar.hs  
foo_bar.hs:1:0: The function `main' is not defined in module `Main'

Comment: @aXqd Wrong hint, sorry. I've updated my answer. I've tested it locally, and it works; the object file will be generated.